# How to preload data from the database in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

First of all, sorry if I make grammatical mistakes, I'm a Spanish speaker and I don't speak English well, I hope there are no problems :)

Let me put you in context first. I am learning how to handle VueJS together with Laravel.

My application, once the user enters his credentials, the backend generates a series of session variables (like his personal data, list of users below him, permissions inside the application, etc...). All that data is obtained from the database and can change at **any time** by another administrator or by myself (for example if they change my username).

In my *#app* (in the root of the application) I have those variables set for VueJS to handle them easily. Every 5 seconds I make a request to update those variables (I use Laravel and not NodeJS so I'm content for it to be this way).

```
data() {
    return {
        loggedUser: {},
        selectedUser: {},
    }
},
```

In *#app* > *beforeCreate()* I have the following:

```
beforeCreate() {
    //información de usuarios
    axios.get('/api/session').then((res) => {
        this.loggedUser = res.data.loggedUser;
        this.selectedUser = res.data.selectedUser;
        this.usersList = res.data.usersList;
    })
}
```

In such a way that those variables will be filled with what you get from the database. The problem is that the loading of that data is slower than the loading of the components themselves. In my component "Profile" that is loaded with vue-router:

```
data() {
    return {
        userModified: {
            first_name: this.userLogged.first_name,
            last_name: this.userLogged.last_name,
            email: this.userLogged.email,
        }
    }
},
```

The problem: when I directly enter in *localhost/profile*, **userLogged** is *undefined* because it has not had time to make the request and the component loads with those undefined variables.

If I load the page in *"/"* and then change to *"/profile"* yes, because the #app has already loaded those variables in advance. How do I preload that information before the components load?

Comment: I usually persist the user with vuex when the 1st time the app loads . note on the 5 seconds fetching loop, try websocket service like pusher.

Comment: thank you for your answer but, what happens if some data of the logged in user changes, does vuex refresh the data when it detects a change or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: if changes in the server, you can use WebSocket for that. when something is modified in the server, you can notify the front end that something has changed. then u can fetch new data.